# Ckeditor with ejs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ejs

I am having trouble adding ckeditor inside my ejs file. I am importing it as a script file from my public folder

> Head of ejs file

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Editor -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I am certain that it is looking at the right path as I don't have the console errors like I once did. Then in a textarea I used the class of editor just as a I saw in the docs but, when I go to view the editor its still just a textarea with its bootstrap classes

> Textarea I want to change

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for=""></label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control mb-2 editor" placeholder="Your message" name="message"></textarea>
 </div>
```

is there something I am doing wrong or does ckeditor not work with ejs?

Comment: Please check for if JS is loaded from the page source.

Comment: Verified that it is in the source

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing with JS method on load.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ID_OF_TEXTAREA');
```

Comment: Recieving this error

**ckeditor.js:348 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined
    at a (ckeditor.js:348)
    at Object.CKEDITOR.replace (ckeditor.js:352)
    at dashboard:28**

**when I added to the top of page this** 

`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
    </script>`

Comment: what is ID of your textarea. Try fetching element using  getElementByID and check if you can fetch element.

Answer (score 0):

I know that maybe too late but may it helps others in future.
So, ensuring that the path to ckeditor.js is correct you have just to add this script
`<script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace( "name of text area");</script>`
in case of the question above "message" is the name of textarea so set 
`<script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace( "message");</script>`